# View multiple user interface elements properly

Tags: javafx

I would like to set multiple UI elements visible. There is one problem though. I have a lot of UI elements and it's been set up like this:

```
nameLanguageLabel.setVisible(true);
descriptionLabel.setVisible(true);
mainNameLabel.setVisible(true);
mainURLLabel.setVisible(true);
URLLanguageLabel.setVisible(true);
mainBodyLabel.setVisible(true);
filesLabel.setVisible(true);
fileTypeLabel.setVisible(true);
srcLabel.setVisible(true);
isHeaderImageLabel.setVisible(true);
mainDescriptionTxtField.setVisible(true);
mainIsHeaderImageTxtField.setVisible(true);
mainSrcTxtField.setVisible(true);
mainFileTypeTxtField.setVisible(true);
mainURLTxtField.setVisible(true);
mainNameTxtField.setVisible(true);
```

Is there a way to make the code shorter? It may be something I haven't noticed during the tutorials I've been doing. (It's not the same project).

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/

Comment: Can you give some context (preferably a [MCVE])? Why are you calling `setVisible(true)` - you must have called `setVisible(false)` at some point. Are all these in a container you can just make visible instead?

Comment: I set them in the sceneBuilder as false, which means the generated FXML file with all the elements are set on visible false. They're indeed in a container (pane). I just realized it 5 seconds, after I asked. Thank you @James_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the elements are in a container. I've set it to visible false, and set it visible, whenever I need it. It's been reduced to this:

```
mainPane.setVisible(true);
```